# How to edit / format XML response in web service

Tags: web-services, apache, apache-axis

I am using Apache Axis2 to write my first web service. I am following this official [link](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html#axiom).
I observed that if you call sample `StockQuoteService` given in link, it gives following properly indented response :

```
<ns:getPriceResponse xmlns:ns="http://pojo.service.quickstart.samples/xsd">
   <ns:return>42</ns:return>
</ns:getPriceResponse>
```

I want response in specific XML format like

```
<answers>     // All answers should be in single `<answers>` tag.
  <answer> Answer1 </answer>   // Each Answer should be in `<answer>` tag.
  <answer> Answer2 </answer>
</answer>
```

How can I format XML response and add my XML tag ?

~Ajinkya.

Comment: If I get you correctly, what you want to do is not necessarily SOAP. You might need to program the response manually.

Comment: @Martin: Yes. Can you give me any idea how it can be done ?

Comment: With Apache Axis, I am not sure, but I am not a great Java expert. Must you use Java? Will your services receive inputs, or they will be just outputting xml?

Comment: I am using Java. My service takes on string input and should generate XML output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working http://www.marcusschiesser.de/?p=142 :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use XSL Transformations (XSLT) to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But how can I remove `<ns:getPriceResponse>` and `<ns:return>` added by axis2 ?

Comment: My answer is only for "How to edit / format XML response in web service". If you have a very specific need, you should precise your goals. If you want to do common things with web service response, maybe you just want to use JAXB objects ?

Comment: I have my mentioned my exact requirement in question with example of how the response should look like. By editing I also mean to remove some part which I already mentioned. Still let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: How do u think the only service answer "42" will become "Answer1" and "Answer2" for example ?

Comment: I apologize for the mistake. I want the answer in format mentioned above.each answer should be in <answer> tag with all answers in only one <answers> tag. Hope I am not confusing you anymore.

Comment: XSLT will do what you are asking, it's a good answer. Were you wanting @Tristan to write the XSLT for you?